# technical question in Partial differential equation

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

I starting to learn Partial differential equation and I got the following question:

u=u(x,y) is a solution for cauchy problem:

$u_t+u_x-u=0$,

$u|_{t=0}=
\begin{cases}
0,&x\leq 0\\\\
x/\epsilon,&0\leq x\leq \epsilon\\\\
1, &\epsilon \leq x
\end{cases}
$

calcultate: 
 $\lim_{\epsilon\to 0}\int_{-\infty}^\infty u_xxdx$

what is the part of $u_t$ in the equation?
it should not be a function of only x and y?

I don't really know how to treat it.

Comment: It is probably a misprint: $u=u(t,x)$.

Comment: this is what I thought. thank you.